# Show that if sequence is not bounded then the series does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ an orthonormal basis. Let $x\in H$. I want to show that if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is not bounded, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty| a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2$ does not converge.

Edit: Indeed, what I'm supposed to show is, if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is not bounded, then there exists $x\in H$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty| a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2$ does not converge.

Thanks.

Comment: If $x = 0$, the series converges whatever $(a_n)$ is. What one can show is that if $(a_n)$ isn't bounded, then there is an $x\in H$ such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lvert a_n\langle x, e_n\rangle\rvert^2 = +\infty$.

Comment: Can I get more hints please...

Comment: Riesz Frigyes, Hugo Steinhaus, Stefan Banach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\{ a_n \}$ is a sequence such that $\sum_n |a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 < \infty$ for all $x\in H$. Then define
$$
           Ax = \sum_n a_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n,\;\; Bx=\sum_n \overline{a_n}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n.
$$
The operators $A$ and $B$ are defined everywhere on $H$ because $\sum_n |a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 < \infty$. Furthermore,
\begin{align}
    \langle Ax,y\rangle & = \langle \lim_N\sum_{n \le N} a_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n,y\rangle \\
   & = \lim_N \langle \sum_{n \le N}a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n,y\rangle \\
   & = \lim_N \sum_{n\le N} a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle \langle e_n,y\rangle \\
   & = \lim_N \langle x, \sum_{n\le N}\overline{a_n}\langle y,e_n\rangle e_n\rangle \\
   & = \langle x,By\rangle
\end{align}
Because of this, $A$ is closed: if $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $Ax_n\rightarrow y$, then the following holds for all $z\in H$:
$$
            \langle Ax,z\rangle= \langle x,Bz\rangle=\lim_n \langle x_n,Bz\rangle = \lim_n \langle Ax_n,z\rangle = \langle y,z\rangle.
$$
Hence $Ax=y$, which proves that $A$ is closed. Therefore $A$ must bounded by the Closed Graph Theorem. That means
$$
                   \|Ax\|^2 = \sum_n |a_n|^2|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 \le \|A\|^2\|x\|^2.
$$
Setting $x=e_n$ gives
$$
                     \|Ae_n\|=|a_n| \le \|A\|,\;\;\; n\ge 1.
$$
Therefore $|a_n|$ must be bounded in order for $A$ to be defined for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks so much.Just I'm not sure how to verify $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,By\rangle$.

Comment: @kingsley : I added the missing steps for you.

Comment: Verified. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$ then $a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$. Hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty| a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2$ converges, whatever $(a_n)$ is.

The same we have if $x=e_k$ for some k. Then $a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $n \ne k$

Etc....